# Rename a web application in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications

If I open Sharepoint Foundation 2010 **Central Administration** web and
select **Application Management** and
click on **Manage Applications**

I can see all my Sharepoint 2010 applications. But How can I rename one of them? Is that at all possible?

**Why do I want this?**
By default Sharepoint installed default web site on port 80. I successfully moved it to port 81 (since I need port 80 for something else), but the name remain the same and is very misleading. The name is `Sharepoint - 80`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the overall goal you're trying to actually accomplish here?  Why do you want to rename it?

Update:  Currently there is no way to rename the web app inside SharePoint short of deleting it and recreating it.

Comment: By default it got installed on port 80. I managed to *move* it to some other port (because I need 80 for something else), but the name is still **Sharepoint - 80** which is very much misleading.

Comment: Deleting and recreating it is what has to be done. No way of renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

This was correctly answered on SharePoint SE where you posted this same question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/16672/2881. I have also written up a simplified version of this solution on my blog here: http://thechriskent.com/2012/04/17/renaming-a-web-application-in-sharepoint-2010/

To summarize, this is done with PowerShell using the following commands:

```
$wapp = Get-SPWebApplication "SharePoint - 80"
$wapp.Name = "Magical Web App"
$wapp.Update()
```

This can be in a script or directly typed into the Powershell management console. Be aware, however, **that this will not change the IIS website names or application pools**. But these don't need to match for everything to continue working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the AAM and IIS Host header bindings. You can also change the web application name.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/how-to-change-sharepoint-web-application-name-and-url.html#ixzz2aAy5eC5y

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.